# Why do I have a different wallpaper in Activities Overview of Gnome Shell, and how do I remove it?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, activities-overview

When I open the `Activities Overview` in Gnome Shell (cursor in top left corner), my wallpaper changes to a different wallpaper than the one I have selected in the `Background Settings`. Why is this happening and how do I remove the extra wallpaper?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, and here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, maybe this question is out of date but I wonder, did you install gnome alongside unity and which wallpaper change program do you use ? İs it wallch ? I had the same issue with ubuntu in the past, but not with ubuntu gnome.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you've previously set a wallpaper using `Ubuntu Tweak`, with its Tweaks > Desktop > Love Wallpapers HD option. If that's the case, the Activities Overview wallpaper is located in .config/ubuntu-tweak and will be called lovewallpaper.jpg... You can safely remove this file.